# How to use Group By when grouping should be done with multiple rows and columns?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose there is a `document_persons` table like

```
document_id person_id person_type_id
      1         20          5
      1         15          5

      2         20          4

      3         15          4

      4         15          4
      4         20          4
```

The goal is to find out what groups of persons have submitted documents. E.g., persons 20 and 15 with type 5 would be one group (submitted document 1), persons 20 and 15 with type 4 would be another group (submitted document 4), person 15 would be another group (submitted document 3) and so on. How can these groups be obtained?

Furthermore, when the groups are created, how would it be possible to count how many documents each group has submitted?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like a `listagg` function *candidate*. Sample data from line #1 - 8; query begins at line #9.

```
SQL> with document_persons (document_id, person_id, person_type_id) as
  2    (select 1, 20, 5 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 15, 5 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 20, 4 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 15, 4 from dual union all
  6     select 4, 15, 4 from dual union all
  7     select 4, 20, 4 from dual
  8    )
  9  select
 10    document_id,
 11    person_type_id,
 12    listagg(person_id, ', ') within group (order by person_id) list,
 13    count(distinct document_id) count_of_docs
 14  from document_persons
 15  group by document_id,
 16           person_type_id;

DOCUMENT_ID PERSON_TYPE_ID LIST                 COUNT_OF_DOCS
----------- -------------- -------------------- -------------
          1              5 15, 20                           1
          2              4 20                               1
          3              4 15                               1
          4              4 15, 20                           1

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried a select like this, and the problem is count_of_docs - it returns count of rows for document in the table (2 rows for doc 1 and 4, 1 row for 2 and 3), when it should be returning how many documents exist with this group of submitters (1 for all documents)

Comment: Aha; then modify the count function to `count(distinct document_id)`

Comment: Yes, that works for this example. However, if document 5 is added with submitters 15 and 20 of type 5, then yet another row will be created, and count_of_docs for this group will be 1. Is it possible to use this select to then obtain count for each group? Or is it possible to change it so that document 5 doesn't create a new row, but increases the count of the first row in the table?

Comment: I'd say that this doesn't fit what you previously described. Such a row (5-15-5) **would** create a new row. Becuse, if you aggregated on DOCUMENT_ID so the only column to group values by remains PERSON_TYPE_ID, then the final result would be only **2 rows**, and that's certainly not what you wanted.